# NetBeans Profiler - Live Results not shown

Tags: java, netbeans, profiling, profiler

While using NetBeans profiler, it does not shows the "Live Results" / enalbles "Take Snapshot" option.

Therefore, I could not see Live class stack tree. The error is get is: "No Profiling Results available yet"!

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think I've run into this, and I recall that there are some modes that you can run the profiler in that don't give you live results and others that do. I don't remember more though, and I'm not really even sure if that was it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the profiling roots correctly?

See http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-intro.html#cpu for more detailed information about setting up profiling roots and instrumentation filters.